# Set password to a file without encryption

Tags: operating-system, password-protection

I want to protect a file with password but I do not want to encrypt it.
Is it possible?
I am using macOS.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. What you can do is restricting the permissions to that file for example:

```sh
chmod -rw /path/to/file    # remove Read/Write permissions for every user
chmod ug+rw /path/to/file # grand persmission only to owner (user or group).
chown otherUser:otherGroup /path/to/file
```

To access that file, you need to switch the user context for example via `sudo` or `su`.